# What browser to use on old dated Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, browser

I have some business critical software on a VM. It is unsupported and expired in 2012. In order to use it, I have to maintain the date on the VM as year 2012. This presents an issue when I try to use the internet on the VM, as all the browsers I use complain about the security certificates and refuse to connect to many sites. In many cases, I cannot even add exceptions.

- Is there a browser I can use that would allow me to disable all checks for security certificates and just let me use the internet on an "at risk" basis?
- Some other way of allowing me to use the internet without updating the system time?

EDIT: VM is running Windows Server 2008

Comment: which OS is installed on your VM?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But given that you are using a VM, which basically runs in a window on a host, can't you just use the host and run internet there? Or alternatively, setup a server and use Remote Desktop and internet from there?

Comment: Sorry should have said: Windows Server 2008

Comment: How does a Windows Server 2008 license expire?

Comment: @Ramhound It is not the Windows license that has expired, but the bespoke software I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should already have Internet Explorer 7 or higher installed on your machine. You can disable certificate checks for IE by going to:

1. Internet Options > Advanced > Security (scroll-down)
2. Uncheck the option: Check for server certificate revocation
3. Restart IE and try visiting a site

This setting should also disable expiration checks for the certificate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, unfortunately it does not work entirely. Perhaps this is because I have IE 9? However I am able to continue on to using the site once I choose to ignore the error. This is better than what I had before, but I would prefer to not see the error each time. I will mark this as the answer later, unless someone comes up with a more complete answer.

Comment: Hi @SeanDav, do you have the option 'warn about invalid site certificates' in the advanced tab? Not sure if this was removed in IE9 or not.

Comment: No I don't think so. Just have "Warn about certificate address mismatch"